# What are some useful tips to track down a randomly occuring C0000005 Access Violation in C++?

Tags: c++, memory, pointers, access-violation, heap-corruption

I have done some searches on here, MSDN, and through some other forums via Google trying to find any sort of solution to this, but so far am stuck.

I have been looking for a week, trying to track down an access violation error in my C++ Program. I cant really post code here as it is under some IP Restrictions, but basically, it is a loop that is running roughly every 100ms reading bytes from a TCP Connection and placing them onto the back of a std::queue.

After I notice a particular byte sequence come through, I then remove x bytes from the queue and handle them as a message defined in an internal protocol.

What happens is, somewhere inside my application, the queue is becoming corrupted and crashing the application. So pair that with the fact that it is an access violation, it must be a dodgy pointer somewhere.

I have tried to use the VS2005 Debugger and Windbg to find it, I had call stacks to look at but it wasnt much help. All I could work out from it is that the cause is corruption of my internal queue. The reason it crashes is because the header of the message gets send to be parsed, but because it is corrupted everything falls over.

Then I tried Intel Thread Checker but that is far too slow to use in this application, as my program is part of a synchronous multi-threaded system.

Sometimes it will run for 300 reads... sometimes it can do 5000 reads... sometimes it can do 10000 reads before it crashes.

What are some other routes of diagnosis I can try? Am I missing something simple here that I should have checked already? From what I can see, anything being newed has a matching delete, and I am using Boost Librarys for Shared Pointers and Auto Pointers on long-living objects.

Comment: You mention Intel Thread Checker, so I guess your application is multi-threaded? Do you access, and more importantly modify, the queue from different threads? Do you have proper protection for that (semaphores, mutex etc.)?

Comment: Hi Joachim. Yes we use Mutex's on any shared structures. Also, there are 2 threads that are running this same code as there are 2 TCP Connections doing data transfers in the same protocol. However each one has its own queue.

Comment: IIRC this can also happen when you delete an object that was not new'ed or has already been deleted. But the fact that it randomly crashes sounds like your code is not thread safe.

Answer (score 3):

Use SEH(structured exception handling) to find out which part raises AV.

### SEH in C++ example code from MSDN.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <eh.h>
void SEFunc();
void trans_func( unsigned int, EXCEPTION_POINTERS* );
class SE_Exception
{
private:
    unsigned int nSE;
public:
    SE_Exception() {}
    SE_Exception( unsigned int n ) : nSE( n ) {}
    ~SE_Exception() {}
    unsigned int getSeNumber() { return nSE; }
};
int main( void )
{
    try
    {
        _set_se_translator( trans_func );
        SEFunc();
    }
    catch( SE_Exception e )
    {
        printf( "Caught a __try exception with SE_Exception.\n" );
    }
}
void SEFunc()
{
    __try
    {
        int x, y=0;
        x = 5 / y;
    }
    __finally
    {
        printf( "In finally\n" );
    }
}
void trans_func( unsigned int u, EXCEPTION_POINTERS* pExp )
{
    printf( "In trans_func.\n" );
    throw SE_Exception();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Random crash usually caused by heap corruption, it is hard to find. Past years I  had deal with several heap corruption problems, as I remembered, one of the problems took me a whole weekend to track it down. Here're some suggestions:

1. Try app verifier first. details is in:
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371695(v=vs.85).aspx
   .
2. Gflags:
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549557(v=vs.85).aspx.
   Use it to to enable Page heap verification.
3. The solution 1 and 2 are both using heap verification for your whole
   program, so you may get many exceptions and slow down your program,
   but some of them are not related to your problem. If you know which
   part of code has errors, you can use window API _CrtSetDbgFlag to
   enable heap verifciation, some thing like this:

   `int tmpFlag =  _CrtSetDbgFlag( _CRTDBG_REPORT_FLAG );

   tmpFlag |= _CRTDBG_CHECK_ALWAYS_DF;

   _CrtSetDbgFlag(tmpFlag); // verify heap when alloc and dealloc

   //you code here, if the heap is corrupt, exception will be thrown at next allocation.

   tmpFlag |= ~_CRTDBG_CHECK_ALWAYS_DF;

   _CrtSetDbgFlag(tmpFlag)// do not verify heap`

Comment: Hi Simon, I will give this a go soon. I have just reworked some faulty logic and am testing it first. If it works I will post my solution.